# Can't install windows after linux

Tags: linux, windows-8, installation, windows-installation

I've got an uefi based system with linux on it
I deleted the win 7 partition to install win 8 because the installation failed when it was running on windows

when i try to install windows 8 from usb i get the message "Windows installation encountered an unexpected error. Verify that the installation sources are accessible, and restart the installation.
Error Code: 0xC0000005"
I mention that installer detects my usb stick

And when i try now to reinstall windows 7 i get "Windows could not prepare the computer to boot into the next phase of installation..."

Is there any chance to install win 8 without erasing all hard disk?
Any help is apreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the file system on your disk. Windows 8 would need GPT.

Comment: So where does Linux come in?

Comment: @whs - Windows 8 does not REQUIRE the use of GPT partitions.  I should know I am running it on my system with a MBR partition on a 3TB disk.

Comment: the disk is gpt

Comment: linux is on the second partition (after efi)

Comment: How is the usb stick formatted?  At what stage do you get the error you recieved?

Comment: usb is gpt formatted (with rufus). The error occurs at the first stage of installing, after selecting the the partition